# Passing arguments from static Main in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to C# and having problems passing a field from the static Main method to another method.

Here's the code. I have copied the error at the end of the relevant line.  Using VS2012.

```
namespace SpaceApiTest
{
    class SpaceApiTest
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Input input = new Input();
            input.debug = true; // error CS1513: } expected

            public int getIp(ref Input input)
            {
                input.ip.Add("192.168.119.2");
                return 0;
            }

            SpaceApiTest st = new SpaceApiTest();

            st.getIp(input); // error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface  
                                  member declaration
                               // Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
         }
    }

    public struct Input
    {
        public string ip;
        public string token;
        public bool debug;
    }
} // error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting that error because you have a method within a method. Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Input input = new Input();
    input.debug = true;

    SpaceApiTest st = new SpaceApiTest();
    st.GetIp(ref input); //don't forget ref keyword.
}

public int GetIp(ref Input input)
{
    input.ip.Add("192.168.119.2");
    return 0;    
}
```

Also, in C# (unlike Java), the convention is to have methods start with an uppercase character rather than lowercase. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff926074.aspx) for more information.